# Express inverse of quadratic form in terms of matrix inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Given vector $v$, and invertible square matrix $A$, I'd like to express the inverse of scalar $b$ given by

$b = v^T A v$.

However, rather than writing it down directly as:

$\dfrac{1}{b} = \dfrac{1}{v^T A v}$,

I'd like to express $\dfrac{1}{b}$ in terms of $v$ and $A^{-1}$.

A naive guess would be

$b^{-1} = \dfrac{v^T A^{-1} v}{|v^T v|^2}$

but this does not work unless the matrix $v v^T$ commutes with $A$.

What is the intuition behind this and is it possible to express $b^{-1}$ in terms of $A^{-1}$ given some additional constraints on $A$ and $v$?

Comment: Do you have some reason to believe that this is possible in general?

Comment: If we consider $v$ as an orthogonal matrix $V$ where $V^T V = I$ then we can express $B^{-1} = V^T A^{-1} V$.  My question is a special case of this.

Comment: Seems to me that the situation in your comment, with $V$ an orthogonal matrix, is the special case, not vice-versa.

Comment: Fair enough, one could write $B^{-1} = V^{-1} A^{-1} V^{-T}$ more generally.  The point is that we expect this to be possible for square matrix $V$, but I'm wondering whether we can do it for vector $v$ (or a 'skinny' $V$ more generally).

Comment: That’s not really any different from the first expression. What makes it a special case is that $V$ is an invertible square matrix.